# Can't create new document on POST (mongoose/express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, mongoose

Check My Node.js code Please I want to Save Contact page data in mongoose compass this don't throw any error but also not saving data

`<form action="/" class="contact_form grid" method="POST">`

HTML IS TOTALLY CORRECT WRITTEN I THINK PLEASE TELL ME WHATS WRONG IN THIS APP.JS CODE

```
   const express = require('express');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const app = express();
    const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
    const path = require('path');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ContactPage');
    const port = 3000;
    
    var contactSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
        name:{type:String}, 
        email:{type:String}, 
        project:{type:String}, 
        message:{type:String}
    });
    var Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', contactSchema);
        module.exports = Contact;
    
    app.use('/static', express.static('static')) // For serving static files
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
    
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.get('/', function(req,res){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"))
    });
    app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
            var myData = new Contact(req.body);
            myData.save().then(()=>{
                 res.send(req.body)
            }).catch(()=>{
                res.status(400).send(req.body);
            });
        });
    
    
    
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
      })
```

Check My Node.js code Please I want to Save Contact page data in mongoose compass this don't throw any error but also not saving data

```
<form action="/" class="contact_form grid" method="POST">
                    <div class="contact_inputs grid">
                        <div class="contact_content">
                            <label for="" class="contact_label">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name= "name" class="contact_input">
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact_content">
                            <label for="" class="contact_label">Email</label>
                            <input type="email"name="email" class="contact_input">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="contact_content">
                        <label for="" class="contact_label">Project</label>
                        <input type="text" name="project" class="contact_input">
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact_content">
                        <label for="" class="contact_label">Message</label>
                        <textarea name="" id="" cols="0" rows="7" name = "message" class="contact_input"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="" class="button button--flex">
                            Send Message
                            <i class="fas fa-paper-plane button_icon"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: There's no need to **SHOUT**

Comment: Did the answer work with you

Answer (score 0):

**#1** you are not submitting from HTML, so instead of:

```
<div>
    <a href="" class="button button--flex">
        Send Message
        <i class="fas fa-paper-plane button_icon"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

write:

```
<button type="submit">
    Send Message
</button>
```

---

**#2** express improvements

contactSchema file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
var contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    project: { type: String },
    message: { type: String }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', contactSchema);
```

app file:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path');

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

app.use('/static', express.static('static')) // For serving static files
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"))
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    var { name, email, project, message } = req.body;

    var myData = new Contact({
        name,
        email,
        project,
        message,
    });

    myData.save().then((newData) => {
        res.send(newData)
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(400).send("Error: ", err, " , Data: ", req.body);
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ContactPage')
        .then(() => console.log("Server & DB listening at http://localhost:${port}"))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
})
```